# Why wont this loop work

Tags: python, function, loops

```
def cut(path):
    test = str(foundfiles)
    newList = [s for s in test if test.endswith('.UnitTests.vbproj')]
    for m in newList:
        print m
    return newList
```

This function parses through foundliles which is a list of files in a folder that I have already parsed through of about 20+ files. I need to parse through that list of every file thta ends in ".UnitTests.vbproj" However, I can't get it working. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Edit1: This is what I made my code now, and I get the atrribute error message box saying that 'tuple' object has no attribute 'endswith'

```
def cut(path):
    test = foundfiles
    newList = [s for s in foundfiles if s.endswith('.UnitTests.vbproj')]
    for m in newList:
        print m
    return newList
```

Comment: When you say *I can't get it working*, what do you mean by working/not working?

Comment: I strongly suspect that foundfiles is not in fact a list of strings, but instead a list of tuples which each contain one string. Naturally, if that's the case, 's' will be a tuple, not a string.

Comment: Duplicate question: [This loop should be working but its not](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16587764/214178)

Answer (score 2):

You turned the list into a string. Looping over `test` gives you individual characters instead:

```
>>> foundfiles = ['foo', 'bar']
>>> for c in str(foundfiles):
...     print c
... 
[
'
f
o
o
'
,

'
b
a
r
'
]
```

There is no need to turn `foundfiles` into a string. You also need to test the *elements* of the list, not `test`:

```
newList = [s for s in foundfiles if s.endswith('.UnitTests.vbproj')]
```

Comment: If it's not a string how can I use the .endwith() property then? I thought you could only use that on an object that is a string?

Comment: @user2371187: each element *in* the list is a string. These are assigned one by one to `s` in the list comprehension, so we test `s.endswith()`.

Comment: @Martijin I just tried your revised code and it still didnt' work.(see Edit) Would it be possible I'm returning foundFiles incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know what's the type of your 'foundfiles'.
Maybe this way will help you:

```
def cut(path):
    import os
    newlist = []
    for parent,dirnames,filenames in os.walk(path):
        for FileName in filenames:
            fileName = os.path.join(parent,FileName)
            if fileName.endswith('.UnitTests.vbproj'):newlist.append(fileName)
   return newlist
```